# Multidimensional arrays in Powershell like in PHP for Post

Tags: php, arrays, powershell

I try to submit a Post to a Restful WebService written in C#. There is an object class for it containing several parameters and a list of objects from another type. I can build the post parameters in PHP but not in Powershell. Is there any way to do that?

I already tried several types of collection like array or hash but some of the approaches did not work because their structure where wrong and some others did not contain the information. One approach contained  a wrong combination.

```
$params = array('param1' => 'value1', 
'param2' => 'value2', 
'paramList' => array('title1', 'title2'), 
'paramObject' => array(array("objectParam1" => "objectValue1","objectParam2"=>"objectValue2"), array("objectParam1"=>"objectValue3","objectParam2"=>"objectValue4"), array("objectParam1"=>"objectValue5","objectParam2"=>"objectValue6")));
```

This is working fine. In Poweshell I tried something like:

```
$paramList = {'title1'; 'title2'}; and in the post body: 
{
    ...
    "paramList" = $paramList;
    ...
}
```

That concatenates both values to "title1; title2" and there is only one entry but there should be two seperate values.

And the second Problem is the multidimensional array for the paramObject. I have no idea how to do that.

In the C# webservice the class is something like:

```
public class ExampleClass
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> paramList { get; set; }
    public ParamObject paramobject {get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ParamObject
{
    public string objectParam1 {get; set; }
    public string objectParam2 {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `{'title1'; 'title2'}` => `@('title1'; 'title2')`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. In Webservice the value is not of type string (but System.Object[]) so it wasn't posted correctly

Comment: Convert arrays to JSON before sending.

Comment: I converted it resulting in `param1":"value1","paramList":["title1","title2"]`
No change, still not working

Comment: Try to translate it to a PowerShell object via Json: `$params` → [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) → [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)  → [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression)

Comment: @user6695058 Please show your code.with `$params` initialization.